# Paypal mulicurrency payments

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

On our site user can make paypal donations to other users in different currencies, but we want to hold payment statistics in USD, is there any way to get in the paypal IPN payment gross, automaticly converted to US Dollars?

Comment: why don't you achieve this by getting the gross in that currency and then multiplying it by the current USD rate...?

Comment: AlphaMale, how can I get current USD rate from paypal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you achieve this by getting the gross in that currency and then multiplying it by the current USD rate. you can not get it in IPN because it sends variable only relating to your transaction. you need to do it manually when variables are received.

curent currency rates can be get by PayPal Api for currency conversion, here is link to documentation:

[PayPal Currency Conversion API](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/convertcurrency-api-operation)

Hope this helps.